# How to select count of records from order and order line tables group by date?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, nested, left-join

My system has `Order` and `OrderLine` tables.
We can consider them as follows:
(Please don't consider the syntax part).

Order:

```
OrderId int(11) not null auto increment
customerId int(11)
orderdate datetime
...
```

OrderLine:

```
OrderId int(11)
productId int(11)
orderdate datetime
rate, total, ...
```

I need a hint / pointer to write a query in MySQL which can give me total number of orders and items (which are part of orderlines) grouped by `orderdate`. In other words, I need a query which can display information from two different tables (basically, some counts) which are not 1:1 (Eg: in this case, one order can consist of many items). What I need is only the count. The relationship between the tables is `OrderId`. But, that is not relevant to me as I need to look at `OrderDate` and group them in both the tables.

Eg:

```
Date         Orders        Items
2015-08-10    4747        58729
2015-08-11    4822        47593
2015-08-12    5219        52842
```

What I have done so far is something like this:

```
Select count(*) from order group by date(orderdate)
Select count(*) from orderline group by date(orderdate)
```

I also tried joining using LEFT join. But, I could not get the desired results.

Any help in combining the data (mainly count) of multiple tables in a single select will help me.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Show your attempt. We are not here to write code for you.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't mean you need to give me the code. What I need is a pointer where I can learn how to address this problem. Some hints or pointers. I will try to summarize my attempt (with my current system) and present it to you here. However, due to privacy issue, I cannot share that in this forum as is. I appreciate your immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subselect for counting orderline - something like this:

```
select date(orderdate),count(*),
  (select count(*) from OrderLine 
   where date(OrderLine.orderdate)=date(Order.orderdate)) 
from Order 
group by date(orderdate);
```